# Autocomplete jQuery Source

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have this returned ***json***, how can I tell ***source*** to get ***name*** only?

```
var availableTags='
     [
                { name: "one", num: '1', index: '0' }, 
                { name: "two", num: '2', index: '1' },
                { name: "three", num: '3', index: '2' },
                { name: "four", num: '4', index: '3' },
                { name: "five", num: '5', index: '4' },
                { name: "six", num: '6', index: '5' },
                { name: "seven", num: '7', index: '6' }
     ]';
```

> $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
>   source: availableTags
>   });

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var availableTags='
 [
            { name: "one", num: '1', index: '0' }, 
            { name: "two", num: '2', index: '1' },
            { name: "three", num: '3', index: '2' },
            { name: "four", num: '4', index: '3' },
            { name: "five", num: '5', index: '4' },
            { name: "six", num: '6', index: '5' },
            { name: "seven", num: '7', index: '6' }
 ]';
var arr = JSON.parse(availableTags).map(function(a){return a.name;});
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: arr
});
```

This JSON haven't got a good format, this will work as js object:

```
var availableTags=
 [
            { name: "one", num: '1', index: '0' }, 
            { name: "two", num: '2', index: '1' },
            { name: "three", num: '3', index: '2' },
            { name: "four", num: '4', index: '3' },
            { name: "five", num: '5', index: '4' },
            { name: "six", num: '6', index: '5' },
            { name: "seven", num: '7', index: '6' }
 ];
var arr = availableTags.map(function(a){return a.name;});
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: arr
});
```

Other option is good JSON format:

```
var availableTags='[{"name":"one","num":"1","index":"0"},'+
                '{"name":"two", "num": "2", "index": "1" },'+
                '{ "name": "three", "num": "3", "index": "2" },'+
                '{ "name": "four", "num": "4", "index": "3" },'+
                '{ "name": "five", "num": "5", "index": "4" },'+
                '{ "name": "six", "num": "6", "index": "5" },'+
                '{ "name": "seven", "num": "7", "index": "6" }]';

var arr = JSON.parse(availableTags).map(function(a){return a.name;});
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: arr
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: wow it worked now, nice job!! , thank you, now I have two last questions  according to this question, what about the usage of select: function (a) {
   alert(brr[1]);
        }
how to do it?

Also, according to source, how to get a specific data from returned json (not from variable as availableTags) but from php page, 
 x = "getname.php?name=" + $('#searchInput').val(); 
source: x,